# Create an account in firebase without firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Heyy Devs.. I'm creating an Android app using firebase in which phonenumber authentication is required. But I want to use my own otp verification system..
is it possible to create users in firebase by using our own otp verification system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [manage user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) that you authenticate any way you want on your backend.  You can [create custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for them for your frontend.

You won't be able to do any of this without custom backend support that you manage for your app.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it??